# Is dropbox api for mobile apps uses local dropbox folder to get and store files?

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch-2, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to use dropbox as file storage for my app. I go through the dropbox api for different platforms, but i couldn't find out, what mechanism they use. Suppose if the app is Android app, and a file need to save. Will the api use local dropbox folder to store the file and let the folder sync itself or it will save itself to the dropbox server???
Please help me in this regard.
Please also help me to know, if i choose Sencha touch then it help me to integrate dropbox javascript api for file chooser and saver???

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The official Dropbox for Android app isn't directly involved with API content calls, so when you're using the API you're not interacting with whatever caching/local storage it might be have.

The [Dropbox Android Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android) makes API calls directly to the Dropbox servers, so files you upload are stored only on the server, unless you also store them locally yourself.

The [Dropbox Android Sync SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android) uses a local cache in addition to syncing to the Dropbox servers, so they're automatically stored in both places.

The [Drop-ins](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins) are different. The [Dropbox Chooser for Android](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android) does interact with the official Dropbox app.

I recommend working through the tutorial for whichever API you want to use.